# Python unicode utf-8 || PRINT prints "wąż" correctly, but in a List1 the same "wąż" string is printed as 'w\xc4\x85\xc5\xbc'

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I declared the utf-8 encoding and when I `print "wąż"` or other uncommon characters, terminal properly prints out "wąż".

But when I have a list with a string "wąż" and print the whole list, I get `'w\xc4\x85\xc5\xbc'`.

The code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

list1 = ['wąż']
```

But when I print the whole list1:

```
>>>print list1
['w\xc4\x85\xc5\xbc']
```

When I print list1[0] or simply print the string "wąż", it prints correctly:

```
>>>print list1[0]
>>>print "wąż"
wąż
wąż
```

---

*An hour later...*

Okay so I tried to encode the list in utf-8 with `[x.encode('utf-8') for x in list1]`, but this threw me an Error: *UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128).*

So I checked my current encoding with the code below, and turns out I had `ascii`.

```
import sys
reload(sys)
print sys.getdefaultencoding()
```

So I change the encoding to `utf-8` with: `sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")` and it properly prints that I have `utf-8` right now.

So again I go with:

`>>>[x.encode('utf-8') for x in list1]`

`>>>print list1`

`['w\xc4\x85\xc5\xbc']`

But it changes nothing. It still refuses to display the correct characters.

Comment: Unicode strings require `u` prefix in Python 2.x: `list1 = [u'wąż']`

Comment: Your encoding isn't UTF-8. Try `'mbcs'`.

Comment: You already know the answer...`print list1[0]` displays correctly.  Python 2's default is to display escape codes for strings in lists...so don't print the list using Python's default.  Make your own (or switch to Python 3, which changed the default behavior and does what you want).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
>> meh = u'wąż'.encode('utf-8')

>> print meh.decode('utf-8')
wąż
```

So you basically encode/decode the unicode on the basis of a specified encoding.

Its described well here: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#the-unicode-type